# SSRS Tablix Sorting w/Row & Column Group

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, matrix

My matrix has a row group (QuestionText) and a Column Group (AnswerText).

It looks like this:

```
                [AnswerText]
[QuestionText]  [AnswerCount]
```

My Data looks like this:

```
QuestionText    AnswerText     AnswerCount
Question 1      Yes            2
Question 1      No             1
Question 2      Yes            3
Question 2      No             4
```

Which renders as follows:

```
                Yes            No
Question 1      2              1
Question 2      3              4
```

What I'd like to do is to sort by the Yes or No.  Please note that both the questions and answers are just examples, they answers could be flag colors & red, white, blue...

Is this possible?  I've seen someone say "it's hard".  I'm ok with hard, I just need to know how.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/b4a242ce-e2de-463e-8732-a9f8abe493e4

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

did you try just adding an order by in your sql?  so you would order by QuestionText then AnswerText.

Comment: @Bennett Dill, do you mean you want a user to be able to click something to change the sort order?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Bennett Dill. Is this what you're looking for? http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/02/60666.aspx

Comment: Kind of.  That's a table and its directly sorting tabular data.  I have a matrix and want to sort on grouped columns.  It just doesn't work the same way...

Comment: @Bennett Dill, hmm.  It should work pretty similarly in a matrix.  I found this article which either might help or make things more confusing http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3637921_2/Black-Belt-Components--Interactive-Sorts-within-a-Matrix-Data-Region.htm

Answer (score 1):

I might not be grasping this correctly, but do you just want to sort by ascending/descending # of Yes's & No's?

Try this...  Go to the answertext header, and right click, then in the properties, go to the interactive sorting tab.

Select "Groups" instead of Details (radial button).
In the sort by: box, select your answer text group.
In the last section, where it says:  apply this sorting to all groups and data regions in:
Select your entire matrix/tablix.  Not positive, but I had a matrix and that last step was the key to sorting it...in drilldowns or groupings, etc..., sorting only works if you apply it to the whole tablix.